# Using the <include> tag in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

From what I understand the `<include>` tag is basically a copy and paste so I created a view with a couple `textviews` in it and I replicate that a few times

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="#000000">

            <include android:id="@+id/frame_one" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_two" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_three" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_four" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_five" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_six" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_seven" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_eight" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_nine" layout="@layout/frame_layout_normal"/>
            <include android:id="@+id/frame_ten" layout="@layout/frame_layout_last"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

now my question is how can I change the `textview` text individually for each of the include tags I created?

obviously I have to get the layout's view id but not sure what to do after that?

this is all that is in the `frame_layout_normal`

```
    <TextView android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/frame_name"
    android:layout_width="121dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/frame_number"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="121dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

Comment: You should wrap frame_layout_normal up in some form of layout, such as a LinearLayout, so that you can assign an id to the top level object in your <include> and pull it out by id as in my answer, and then pull out individual fields from that LinearLayout by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you wrap the contents of frame_layout_normal in a LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout frameOne = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_one);
TextView frameOneName = (TextView) frameOne.findViewById(R.id.frame_name);
```

`<include>` lets you set the id for the top level element, which you are already doing, so just use those ids to get your frames.

Comment: but I have more than one textview in that layout so how can I set them differently?

Comment: I've updated my answer after seeing your frame_layout_normal contents

Comment: doing that gives me `nullpointer` on the textview, do I need to get the layout parent first? ie. `LineaLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(r.id.linearLayout1)`?

Comment: Yes.  Note that you're calling findViewById on the LinearLayout for the second call, so you need to have the parent in order to do that.